# Eclipse clean+Build vs only Build

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any difference if I perform clean + Build Vs only Build in Eclipse?

I am aware that clean will remove all compiled classes.

But if I only build it will just overwrite them isn't it?

So what is the advantage of performing clean + Build Over only performing Build.

Comment: And for the record: consider cleaning up comments that are no longer required - as they do not contribute to the actual question/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of the incremental eclipse build is to give you **better** performance - whilst still ensuring *integrity*.

When you update your files (via your source code management tool) and files get erased, eclipse will detect that too - and automatically remove the corresponding artifacts, too! eclipse is really smart about dependencies and it will do its best to get things right without throwing away everything. Of course - the one precondition here: you have to **refresh** eclipse so that it checks file system contents to actually figure when things have changed! And of course, you want to have *built automatically* enabled!

You should see *clean build* as your last resort. Normally you only need it when eclipse is somehow "messed" up internally.

More of *anecdotal* evidence: our eclipse projects are **large** (a full clean build takes two minutes, and ends up with 100 000+ warnings). This means that each git fetch/rebase can result in a lot of files added/changed/deleted. Still I do not need to run a clean build - I do not even recall the last time a clean build was required. And still everything works nicely, and no pillage of garbage in my output directories!

The one exception in my eyes: when you are using SVN repositories and SVN plugins for eclipse - then the need for "clean builds" *might* be noticeably higher. As all SVN plugins for eclipsee do not work perfect for large code bases. They do all kinds of internal caching - and I have seen many incidents when a clean build and eclipse restart was necessary to really get back to a working environment. ( for the record: the answer to such issues is to get rid of SVN within eclipse, for example by using the git-svn tooling )

Answer (score 4):

Build without clean attempts to build only resources that have changed or need to be rebuilt for some other reasons.

Sometimes you still need to do a clean in order to get a clean slate and not have obsolete resources end up breaking your build or software.

For example if you delete a class, and do a build without clean, the previously compiled class file would still exist and potentially cause problems.

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman, so build without clean doesn't have any usage then? basically i was asking from time perspective as clean+ build takes more time than only build if project is large.

Comment: No, that's not at all what I said.

Comment: for example, after taking update from Repository(e.g. SVN) clean+Build option seem more appropriate as there might be deletion of some files right?

Comment: I disagree with the last paragraph. To my knowledge: when you delete a file from your sources and refresh eclipse, it detects "class" gone - and deletes the corresponding artifacts. You see - the IDE will also show you errors for other classes depending on the now deleted entity. So why should eclipse *not* delete the corresponding .class from its output tree?!

Comment: @GhostCat You need to have "Build automatically" on for that, although yeah maybe deleting a class is a bad example.

Comment: Still, good answer. And I stole that "build automatically" for my answer ... so have my vote here ;-)